# Modify class defined by var on a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, var

I want to add class "unblock" to all elements contanining *desbloquear* var value (in this case, taken from clicked a element's id).

I am not able to do this... as there are several ements that should receive the new class, I can not set the same id to them (to be equal as "a" id). How could I say, on the last line of the function, that all items containing "a" class (*desbloquear* var value) should add class unblock?

I've tried

```
$(.desbloquear).addClass('unblock');
```

and

```
$(".desbloquear").addClass('unblock');
```

without result...

```
$('a').on('click', unblock);

function unblock(){

    var desbloquear = $(this).attr('id');

    $(desbloquear).addClass('unblock');

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery- Using a variable as a selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784925/jquery-using-a-variable-as-a-selector)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*all items containing "a" class (desbloquear var value) should add class unblock*

I might not got your question correctly but by above line. It looks that you want to add a class `unblock` to elements those have some specific class. if yes then you can do like this

```
function unblock(){

    var desbloquear = $(this).attr('class');

    $('.'+ desbloquear).addClass('unblock');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**[class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)** should begins with a `.`

Just try,

```
$('.' + desbloquear).addClass('unblock');
```

Full code:

```
$('a').on('click', unblock);

function unblock() {
    var desbloquear = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.' + desbloquear).addClass('unblock');    
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but in this case it was items with an specific CLASS (not id) which should have the unblock class added. Anyway thank you, useful tip.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are correct, Id's should be unique, you can use class instead

You will need a `.` to specify a class attribute in selector

```
$('.'+desbloquear).addClass('unblock');
```